# Info.plist Dictionary to Dictionary of type Enum:String

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, info.plist

I'm trying to take a dictionary from my Info.plist and save it as a Dictionary of type Enum: String

To better explain, I'm trying to convert the urlDict below to be a Dictionary of type  but keep getting fatal error.

I can't figure out why 
`let enumDict = urlDict["keys"] as? Dictionary<URLKeys, String>` does not work

The enum has a raw type of String and has a case for keyOne.

```
enum URLKeys: String {
    case keyOne = "keyOne"
}

var keysDictionary = Dictionary<String, Any>()
keysDictionary["keyOne"] = "abc"

var urlDict = Dictionary<String, Any>()
urlDict["keys"] = keysDictionary

guard let enumDict = urlDict["keys"] as? Dictionary<URLKeys, String> else {
    fatalError()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `forEach` and create a URLKeys for each key and cast each value to string

```
var enumDict:[URLKeys: String] = [:]
keysDictionary.forEach { 
    if let key = URLKeys(rawValue: $0.0), let value = $0.1 as? String {
        enumDict[key] = value
    }
}
```